# The XSS Filter modifies content

Tags: asp.net, json, xss, microsoft-edge

I have asp.net `WEB API`  where on one action I put `json` string in url parameter, for example:

```
http://example.com?config=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22paramete1%22%3A%22value1%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22serverulr%22%3A%22http%2F%2Fexample.com%22%0D%0A%7D
```

where config parameter contains encoded json:

```
{
    "paramete1":"value1",
    "serverulr":"http//example.com"
}
```

Everything works fine for all browsers, I only have problems with Microsoft edge and Internet Explorer. In console it shows me next:

```
SEC7130: Potential cross-site scripting detected in 'http://example.com?config=%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22paramete1%22%3A%22value1%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%22serverulr%22%3A%22http%2F%2Fexample.com%22%0D%0A%7D'. The content has been modified by the XSS Filter.
```

And after that my json looks like below:

```
{
    "paramete1":"value1",
    "serverulr":"http//example^com"
}
```

Do have any idea how to avoid this issue?

Comment: Why don't you use `request payload` to send `json`? using verbs such as put or post instead of get

Comment: I can use only get requests.

Answer (score 0):

I considered few ways to avoid this.
First was to add custom header and put this config into this header, but then I faced other problem cause in same cases this url has to be used in iframe. 
So I decided to encode this value into base64 and it work fine.